# Can a broken film sprocket mechanism on a Minolta 7000 AF be fixed?

Tags: lens, zoom, minolta

My granddaughter was given an old Minolta 7000 AF with a Sigma Zoom 28-80 lens. The film sprocket mechanism doesn't work. Is this fixable? Or would the lens be compatible with a new Minolta X-700?

Comment: Thank you very much, you've answered all my questions!

Answer (score 2):

It's very hard to say if a broken camera is (economically) fixable, without someone spending time examining it. There are not many places offering repair services on cameras like this - the problem is that they are not particularly worth saving, considering it is more often easier to just buy another working one from eBay. Even though it's an "old" camera, it still relies on internal electronics, which were never really meant to be easily repairable nor last forever.

The Minolta X-700 is actually an older camera than the 7000, and uses an older lens mount called the Minolta SR-mount. The 7000 uses the Minolta A-mount, i.e. the Sigma lens is an A-mount lens. A-mount lenses are not backwards-compatible with SR-mount cameras.

Minolta merged with Konica to become Konica Minolta, and later Sony bought some of Konica Minolta's technology, so finally Sony started producing digital cameras using the A-mount, which would be compatible with the Sigma lens. But to be honest, that Sigma lens is not a high-quality lens, and it's really not worth going to the expense of buying a Sony camera solely so that that lens can be used. (Note that Sony has moved on also, and now produces cameras with a different mount, called the E-mount.)

Summary - if the aim here is to get the Sigma lens back in use again for film photography, I think the easiest/cheapest solution is to find a working Minolta A-mount camera body for sale. Look into one of the later Minolta models - the [Minolta Maxxum 4 (AKA Minolta Dynax 4)](https://web.archive.org/web/20030330150030if_/http://www.minoltaeurope.com:80/pe/pdfs/dynax_4_cat_e.pdf) for example would be a good basic/starter choice.